# Remove from card Ajax method not working in MVC4 tutorial for Music Store Shopping Card

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I followed the [MVC4 Music Store tutorial for making a shopping card](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-8). Unfortunately, when I use the RemoveFromCard function I get the following message:

```
The resource cannot be found. 
  Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its  
  dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily   
  unavailable. Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled 
  correctly. 

Requested URL: /ShoppingCart/RemoveFromCart/1
```

The code I use on the View Page is the following:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        // Document.ready -> link up remove event handler
        $(".RemoveLink").click(function () {
            // Get the id from the link
            var recordToDelete = $(this).attr("data-id");
            if (recordToDelete != '') {
                // Perform the ajax post
                $.post("/ShoppingCart/RemoveFromCart", { "id": recordToDelete },
                function (data) {
                    // Successful requests get here
                    // Update the page elements
                    if (data.ItemCount == 0) {
                        $('#row-' + data.DeleteId).fadeOut('slow');
                    }
                    else {
                         $('#item-count-' + data.DeleteId).text(data.ItemCount);
                    }

                    $('#cart-total').text(data.CartTotal);
                    $('#update-message').text(data.Message);
                    $('#cart-status').text('Cart (' + data.CartCount + ')');
                });
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

With the following actionlink:

```
<td>
                <%: Ajax.ActionLink("Remove from cart", "RemoveFromCart",
                        new { id = item.RecordId },
                        new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "handleUpdate" })%>
            </td>
```

Furthermore,

I have this method in ShoppingCard.cs

```
public int RemoveFromCart(int id) //code
```

Why does it not find this method? I would be very grateful for some help!

Comment: do you have [HttpPost] on top of your method?

Comment: @MattBodily Thank you, no I did not... This does not solve the problem though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I solved the problem... I changed the actionlink to:

```
<a href="#" class="RemoveLink" data-id="<%:item.RecordId %>">Remove from cart</a>
```

and now it is working.